# What should I do when no root file system is defined during installation?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

[image]
NOTE: please be careful to think this question as duplicate.

1. I chose install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 8.
2. there is just one NTFS disk C in my computer.
3. It does not create a new disk before boot from USB disk.

the guide does not mention this step. I have read the similar question but it does not help.

It seems that I should partition my disk first. but how?

Is there some buttons to partition? I do not know how does this picture come up:

[image]

looks like I miss something.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you want to partition your drive,then exit the ubuntu installer and then install gparted by running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install gparted` on terminal.

Comment: then upload the gparted screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

See the advanced partition tool for more control in the above dialog box.

- Click on it, you will be given the list of partitions.
- Choose the partition where you want to install Ubuntu.
- Format that partition as ext4, and mount it as "root".

In the next step It will ask for swap space, which you can skip.

Comment: thank you but I really donot know what you are talking about.which button shoul I hit? "mount it as root", what does "it" refer to?

Comment: I guess you are using advanced partition tool ? In that case, you can create new partition from free space, select ext4 format and below it in the dialog box itself ,there will be an option "Mount". click on that option and mount it as "/"

Comment: I am not sure. I chose "something else". Because the other choice is replace the windows 8, which obviously is not the choice.

Comment: I have tried that to. but there are only two free spaces, one is 1MB ,the other is 0MB. I type 30720 MB and failed in both.

Comment: there simply no 'advanced partition tool' button. I will show you that in a new question. hold on

Comment: In sb4, there is 480 GB disk space, you can create required space from that partition

Comment: Don't ask a new question. I will rewrite my answer with complete details

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12113/discussion-between-rakesh-godhala-and-pythoner)

Comment: oh really sorry , when I see your infomation, I already made:http://askubuntu.com/questions/394566/which-button-should-i-hit