# Have problems resizing NTFS disk. What should I do to create a 10GB free space disk?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

Rakesh Godhala said:

> You can select the partition as ntfs, resize the partition to 470GB.

So I click the /dev/sdb4, "change..." button, comes up "edit partition" dialog.

But after selecting "use as" to "NTFS" , there is no option for me to resize the C partition to 470GB.

So, what should I do to create a 10GB free space disk?

Could you please tell me **which buttons** I should hit to get over this problem?

All buttons are showed in the pictures I have uploaded at:

[Which button should I hit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/394566/which-button-should-i-hit).

OK, I chose "something else" , because I cannot choose "replace windows 8 with Ubuntu".

I click "continue", so I faced the dialog (as the two pictures in previous question show).

I do not know which buttons should I hit.

This is the picture:
[image]

Comment: plz upload gparted screenshot.And explain your problem simply in this question.

Comment: sorry, but I donot know what does " gparted screenshot" means. you can see the pictures in the previous question.

Comment: pythoner don't resize the partition using installer,please exit the installer and then open up the terminal,then run these commands on it `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted`.After the gparted partition Editor was opened,take a screenshot and upload it here.

Comment: ohh what you are doing in this http://askubuntu.com/questions/394566/which-button-should-i-hit ,why do you change the sdb4 partition into ext4 filesystem.

Comment: @Avinash Raj that is what I did in the first. I know it was wrong. but what should I do? all I want to is a space that can allow me to coninue. but the dialog really said nothing about how to creat new free spaces.

Comment: plz upload the screenshot.So that it will be so easy for us to help you.

Comment: Ok but what does " then open up the terminal" mean? my OS is windows 8, and is that means I go back to windows 8, and run the cmd.exe, enter the excat words "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get install gparted && sudo gparted"?

Comment: no,boot ubuntu live-disk on the system you want to install ubuntu,click on _try ubuntu_ option,a desktop will appears.then press ctrl+alt+t to open the terminal,after that connect to the internet and run the above commands on that terminal.

Comment: @Avinash Raj here comes the picture. sorry I don't how to make and upload sreenshot imgs in ubuntu. so I take a photo, send a email, and thus= =

Comment: let us continue the discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12115/discussion-between-pythoner-and-avinash-raj)

Answer (score 0):

Still I donot know why. here is a better way to avoid such questions:

1.creat a new disk (40GB size or other size you want) in windows 8.

2.boot from USB disk.

problem solved.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)